# angularjs function not working to pull data from github api

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs. It's a GitHub, datacontroller AngularJs program. Actually the data after using a controller, i.e checkbox is not coming and my ng-repeat is not working.

Can any anyone help me with this?

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  var mainController = function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.message = "Angularjs";
    $scope.reposortorder = "stargazers_count";

    var onSuccess = function(response) {
      $scope.obj = response.data;
      $http.get($scope.obj.repos_url).then(onRepoSuccess, onError);
    };

    var onRepoSuccess = function(response) {
      $scope.repos = response.data;
    };

    var onError = function(reason) {
      $scope.error = "could not load the user details";
    };

    $scope.search = function(username) {
      $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username).then(onSuccess, onError);
    };
  };


  var checkbox = function($scope, $filter, $http) {
    
    $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/"+$scope.username)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.repos = data;
        });


    $scope.chckedIndexs = [];

    $scope.checkedIndex = function(repo) {
      if ($scope.chckedIndexs.indexOf(repo) === -1) {
        $scope.chckedIndexs.push(repo);
      } else {
        $scope.chckedIndexs.splice($scope.chckedIndexs.indexOf(repo), 1);
      }
    };

    $scope.selectedRepos = function() {
      return $filter('repo.name')($scope.repos, {
        checked: true
      });
    };

    $scope.remove = function(index) {
      angular.forEach($scope.chckedIndexs, function(value, index) {
        var index = $scope.repos.indexOf(value);
        $scope.repos.splice($scope.repos.indexOf(value), 1);
      });
      $scope.chckedIndexs = [];
    };
    
      $scope.checkAll = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.repos, function(repo) {
      repo.select = $scope.selectAll;
    });
  };


  };

  app.controller("mainController", mainController);

  app.controller("checkbox", checkbox);

}())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
  <h1>Hello {{message}}</h1>
  {{username}}

<div>
  <form name="searchUser">
    <input type="search" required placeholder="Github Username to find" ng-model="username">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" ng-click="search(username)">
  </form>

  <br />

  <div>{{ error}}</div>

  <p>Name: {{ obj.name }}</p>
  <p>Mail id: {{ obj.email }}</p>
  <p>Image:
    <br /><img ng-src="{{ obj.avatar_url}}" height="150" title="{{ obj.name}} {{obj.lastName}}" /></p>
  
  <div>
    <label>Search:</label>
    <input type="search" ng-model="searchrepo" placeholder="Enter to Search">
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="checkbox">
  
  <p>
    Sort by:
    <select ng-model="reposortorder">
      <option value="name">Name</option>
      <option value="stargazers_count">Stars</option>
      <option value="language">Language</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <div>
    <pre>selected with helper function {{selectedRepos()}}</pre>
     <button ng-click="remove($index)">delete selected</button>
  </div>

  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="checkAll"></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Stars</th>
        <th>Language</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="repo in repos |filter:searchrepo | orderBy:reposortorder">
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="repo.checked" ng-click="checkedIndex(repo)"/></td>
        <td>{{ repo.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ repo.stargazers_count | number }}</td>
        <td>{{ repo.language}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="remove($index)">x </button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Here is the plnkr link https://plnkr.co/edit/T3AK2QnIMq18oEeMuCQk?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="table">
```

This line is reason of malfunctioning. You don't have any "table" controller. You bind repos in your mainController. Remove the "table" controller from that div, everything will work!

Thanks

Comment: I have removed the nested controller but still not working , actually the data is coming from [link](https://api.github.com/users/mojombo) . try mojombo in the search and you will able to know. after editing the plunk [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/T3AK2QnIMq18oEeMuCQk?p=preview)

Comment: Now everything working smoothly, Mistake was that, I was calling the repos to a $scope.obj but was calling the repos to do the function. The plunker link is- [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pga9Ou0sfay2kJDRgpZX?p=preview)

Comment: Good luck! Enjoy the angular world!

Comment: Can anyone tell me how will the select all button will work. Here is the code:    $scope.checkAll = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.repos, function(repo) {
      repo.select = $scope.selectAll;
    });
  };

Comment: @neo.abi1000 Try this plunk -
http://plnkr.co/edit/xnMPfzf13xBQ81rZYX59?p=preview

Looks like the model on checkbox is not working as primitive variable. I put it in a object. Even I don't know the reason!

Comment: Anyway thanks for the help. If you find out why it was not working as a variable please tell me